# jQuery post method doesn't send data

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I made a simple app using jQuery Get and Post methods to retrieve data (users) from json file and add to it.

index.html has a table to display users via ajax and get request and that works fine.
but there is a button to add new users to json file using ajax with post method that takes the new user details from inputs but this one doesn't send the data at all and displays defined at the end of the table.
i console.logged the data that im posting and it looks fine but doesn't get sent.
Note: i used browser-sync first and now im using localhost but same result.

my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!----------------------------------------------------------- Meta tags ----------------------------------------------------->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Logs</title>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First name</th> <th>Last name</th> </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="user">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button class="btn btn-success getUsers"> Get Users </button>
            <form class= "form-inline">
                <input id="id"          class="form-group" placeholder="ID">
                <input id="firstName"   class="form-group" placeholder="First name">
                <input id="lastName"    class="form-group" placeholder="Last name">
            </form>
            <button class="btn btn-success addUsers"> Add a user</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $('.getUsers').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: '/logs/users.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(users){
                    $.each(users, function(i, user){
                        $('.user').append('<tr><td>'+ user.id +'</td> <td>'+ user.firstName +'</td> <td>' +user.lastName + '</td></tr>');
                    });
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        $('.addUsers').click(function(){
            var newUser = {
                id: $('#id').val(),
                firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
                lastName: $('#lastName').val()
            };
            console.log(newUser);
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: '/logs/users.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: newUser,
                success: function(person){
                        $('.user').append('<tr><td>'+ person.id +'</td> <td>'+ person.firstName +'</td> <td>' +person.lastName + '</td></tr>');
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and json file:

```
[
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "firstName": "A",
                    "lastName": "B"
                }
            ]
```

Comment: `POST` needs the URL to be a script that runs on the server and updates the file. You can't post directly to a JSON file.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.. can you please provide some tips?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.. can you provide some tips please?

Comment: You need to learn about server-side scripting. I can't teach you that here.

Comment: i`m using localhost as a server can i still achieve something?

Comment: Not without scripting you can't.

Comment: ok thanks again i found this site so ill try to get the code required

Comment: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're attempting to post to a JSON file which can only define data structure but not function. You need to post to an intermediary script of some sort like PHP or .NET to append the data to your JSON file.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your reply ill have a look at you tube for any REST api toturial